# Выпадающий список PHP AJAX

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Как правильно передать значение, выбранное из выпадающего списка, в *PHP*-скрипт?

Выпадающий список:

```
<div id="city">
    <select name="city">
        <option value="1">Москва</option>
        <option value="2">Санкт-Петербург</option>
        <option value="3">Казань</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

PHP-скрипт:

```
<?php

$link = mysql_connect('...', '...', '...');
if (!$link) {
    die('Ошибка соединения: ' . mysql_error());
}
if (!mysql_select_db('test')) {
    die('Ошибка выбора базы данных: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_query("SET NAMES cp1251");

$cityid = $_REQUEST['city'];
$result=mysql_query("SELECT name FROM street WHERE to_city = '$cityid'");

print "<table>\n";
while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
print "\t<tr>\n";
foreach ($line as $col_value) {
print "\t\t<td>$col_value</td>\n";
}
print "\t</tr>\n";
}
print "</table>\n";

mysql_free_result($result);
mysql_close($link);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Если закрыть глаза на возможность SQL-инъекции в данном коде, и предположить, что подключена библиотека jQuery, то будет так:

```
$("select[name=city]").change( function() { 
    $.post(
      'get_data.php', 
      { city: $('select[name=city]').val() },
      function(html){
          $("#res").html(html);
      }
    );      
});
```

ID города будет содержаться в переменной `$_POST['city']`

Comment: в таком случае в скрипте `$_POST['city']` вместо `$_REQUEST['city']`

Comment: @username Поменял.

Comment: у Вас все правильно. точнее не имеет значения чем Вы передаете данные в скрипт. Мой комметарий адресован автору вопроса. В случае если `$.get` тогда  `$_GET['city']` на стороне скрипта

Comment: Пробовал и $_GET['city'] и $_POST['city']. Не работает(

Comment: @МеньщиковЕвгений консолью Chrome умеешь пользоваться?

Comment: Ну представления имею. но не часто пользуюсь

Comment: С этим не понял что делать $.get('<адрес скрипта>', { city: $('select[name=city]').val() } )

Comment: @МеньщиковЕвгений В общем данные, которые передаются аяксом можно увидеть в консоли Chrome. Строчка кода, которая в ответе - должна запускаться на какое либо событие(например, на изменение значения в списке)

Comment: На изменение события вот мой код:
$("#city").change( function() { 
 $.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "get_data.php",
 data: "city="+$("#city").val(),
 success: function(html){
 $("#res").html(html);
 }
 });
 return false;
});

Comment: $("select[name=city]").change( function() { $.get('<адрес скрипта>', { city: $('select[name=city]').val() } ); });

Comment: С этой строчкой тоже не работает, как будто скрипт не видит

Comment: если не видит скрипт - убедитесь что при `ajax` отправке указываете коректный путь к Вашему `get_data.php`
так как переаете `POST` то и в `get_data.php` принимаете `POST['city']`

Comment: Когда пользуюсь своим вариантом передачи, все работает (и если sql  запрос написать написать например так: SELECT name FROM street WHERE to_city = 1; то форма выдает результат. А вот если вместо единицы поставить $_POST['city'], то уже не рпботает

Comment: @МеньщиковЕвгений Я дополнил ответ.

Comment: Вы скорее всего не получаете выбранный селект.  Попробуйте вариант MAXOPKA

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте корректно передать Ваши данные

```
$("#city").change( function() { 
   var city_id = $("#city").val();
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "get_data.php",
       data: {city: city_id},
       success: function(html){
         $("#res").html(html);
       }
    });

    return false;
});
```

предполагаю что `get_data.php` и `#res` есть

Comment: Как посмотреть что конкретно передалось под $_POST['city']  ?

Comment: лучше всего использовать профилирование или debbug. В вашем случае попробуйте добавить `var_dump($_POST)` в `Ваш get_data.php`

Comment: Получилось за счет варианта МОХОРКА

Answer (score -1):

На изменение события вот мой код:

```
$("#city").change( function() { 
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "get_data.php",
    data: "city="+$("#city").val(),
    success: function(html){
    $("#res").html(html);
    }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: переместите это в свой вопрос